# How to get proportions and counts of a data frame in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame like the one below, but with a lot more rows

```
> df<-data.frame(x1=c(1,1,0,0,1,0),x2=c("a","a","b","a","c","c"))
> df
  x1 x2
1  1  a
2  1  a
3  0  b
4  0  a
5  1  c
6  0  c
```

From `df` I want a data frame where the rows are the unique values of `df$x2` and col1 is the proportion of 1s associated with each letter, and col2 is the count of each letter.  So, my output would be

```
 > getprops(df)
  prop   count
a  .6666   3
b  0       1
c  0.5     2
```

I can think of some elaborate, dirty ways to do this, but I'm looking for something short and efficient.  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try installing plyr and running

```
library(plyr)
df <- data.frame(x1=c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0),
                 label=c("a", "a", "b", "a", "c", "c"))
ddply(df, .(label), summarize, prop = mean(x1), count = length(x1))
#   label      prop count
# 1     a 0.6666667     3
# 2     b 0.0000000     1
# 3     c 0.5000000     2
```

which under the hood applies a split/apply/combine method similar to this in base R:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$x2),
                            with, list(prop  = mean(x1),
                                       count = length(x1))))
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct. He needs proportion. It's different from mean per group.

Comment: @Arun, I think I disagree. OP is looking at the proportion of `1` within each group, so `mean` is appropriate. See that it is giving the OP's expected output.

Comment: If the values of x1 are always in {0, 1}, mean(x1) should be what he wants. Otherwise he can do mean(x1 == 1)

Comment: I could've sworn I saw the result from Mark's earlier answer the same as OP's. (-1) reverted.

Answer (score 6):

I like @RicardoSaporta's solution (+1), but you can use [?prop.table](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/prop.table.html) as well:

```
> df<-data.frame(x1=c(1,1,0,0,1,0),x2=c("a","a","b","a","c","c"))
> df
  x1 x2
1  1  a
2  1  a
3  0  b
4  0  a
5  1  c
6  0  c
> tab <- table(df$x2, df$x1)
> tab

    0 1
  a 1 2
  b 1 0
  c 1 1
> ptab <- prop.table(tab, margin=1)
> ptab

            0         1
  a 0.3333333 0.6666667
  b 1.0000000 0.0000000
  c 0.5000000 0.5000000
> dframe <- data.frame(values=rownames(tab), prop=ptab[,2], count=tab[,2])
> dframe
  values      prop count
a      a 0.6666667     2
b      b 0.0000000     0
c      c 0.5000000     1
```

If you'd like, you can put this together into a single function:

```
getprops <- function(values, indicator){
  tab    <- table(values, indicator)
  ptab   <- prop.table(tab, margin=1)
  dframe <- data.frame(values=rownames(tab), prop=ptab[,2], count=tab[,2])
  return(dframe)
}

> getprops(values=df$x2, indicator=df$x2)
  values      prop count
a      a 0.6666667     2
b      b 0.0000000     0
c      c 0.5000000     1
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a one-liner in `data.table`:

```
> DT[, list(props=sum(x1) / .N, count=.N), by=x2]
   x2     props count
1:  a 0.6666667     3
2:  b 0.0000000     1
3:  c 0.5000000     2
```

*where `DT <- data.table(df)`*

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this does what you want.

```
df<-data.frame(x1=c(1,1,0,0,1,0),x2=c("a","a","b","a","c","c"))

ones <- with(df, aggregate(x1 ~ x2, FUN = sum))
count <- table(df$x2)
prop <- ones$x1 / count

df2 <- data.frame(prop, count)
df2

rownames(df2) <- df2[,3]
df2 <- df2[,c(2,4)]
colnames(df2) <- c('prop', 'count')
df2

       prop count
a 0.6666667     3
b 0.0000000     1
c 0.5000000     2
```

Comment: `aggregate(x1 ~ x2, df, function(x) c(prop = mean(x), count = length(x)))`

Answer (score 2):

Try using `table`

```
tbl <- table(df$x1, df$x2)  
#    a b c
#  0 1 1 1
#  1 2 0 1


tbl["1",] / colSums(tbl)
#          a         b         c 
#  0.6666667 0.0000000 0.5000000
```

For nice output use:

```
data.frame(proportions=tbl["1",] / colSums(tbl))
  proportions
a   0.6666667
b   0.0000000
c   0.5000000
```