# How to calculate the proportion in r?

Tags: r

I have a data frame and I want to calculate the proportion. the table looks like this:

```
                Eligible        Immunised
 Auckland          1778            1426
 Bay of plenty     1194            802
 Canterbury        3461            2731
```

I want to know the proportion across all the districts of who were immunized. I think I need to plus the eligible column and immuised column together then use immunised divided by eligible. But I'm not too sure how to do the code. If anyone can help would be great. Thanks!!

Comment: `sum(df$Immunised)/sum(df$Eligible)` ?

Comment: Take a look at `?prop.table`.

Comment: sum(df$Immunised)/sum(df$Eligible) is correct, it worked. Thanks~

Comment: @akrun all though the answers here show that OP wants to divide one column by another that is not what OP really wants. They want to sum two columns and divide.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13013231/how-can-i-divide-one-column-of-a-data-frame-through-another

Comment: Another related tag is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9447801/dividing-columns-by-colsums-in-r or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17508643/how-to-get-proportions-and-counts-of-a-data-frame-in-r   Note that two of the answers here use the same code as in the dupe tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want ratio of  sum of `Immunised` column with `Eligible` you could do

```
sum(df$Immunised)/sum(df$Eligible)
#[1] 0.770869
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure what you want but it is likely one of these where `m` is defined reproducibly in the Note at the end:

```
prop.table(m)
prop.table(m, 1)
prop.table(m, 2)
prop.table(colSums(m))
prop.table(rowSums(m))
```

### Note

Next time please provide your input in a reproducible form.  I have done it for you this time:

```
Lines <- "Eligible        Immunised
Auckland           1778            1426
Bay of plenty      1194            802
Canterbury         3461            2731"
L <- readLines(textConnection(Lines))
DF <- read.csv(text = gsub(" {5,}", ",", L), as.is = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)
m <- as.matrix(DF)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just divide both columns:

```
df$Proportion <- df$Immunised / df$Eligible

df
                Eligible        Immunised         Proportion
 Auckland          1778            1426            0.8020247
 Bay of plenty     1194            802             0.6716918
 Canterbury        3461            2731            0.7890783
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess what the OP wants is just this:

Data (a data.frame `x`):

```
dput( x )
structure(list(Region = c("Auckland", "Bay of plenty", "Canterbury"
), Eligible = c(1778L, 1194L, 3461L), Immunised = c(1426L, 802L, 
2731L)), .Names = c("Region", "Eligible", "Immunised"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

The `proportion` part is just a new column with the Immunised as a percentage of the Eligible:

```
x$proportion = x$Immunised / x$Eligible
> x
         Region Eligible Immunised proportion
1      Auckland     1778      1426  0.8020247
2 Bay of plenty     1194       802  0.6716918
3    Canterbury     3461      2731  0.7890783
```

That's *very* basic but it seems to be the question.